# Magento send PDF attachment

Tags: php, magento, pdf

I try to send Mail in a Magento CE 1.8.0.0,

I can send pictures et text files, but when i try to send pdf, it's always fail, my attachment size is 0 Ko and i can't open it ...

This is how i work :

```
                    if($filename != '')
                {
                    $mailTemplate
                        ->getMail()
                        ->createAttachment(
                            file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('tmp').'/pjcontact/'.$filename),
                            Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                            Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                            Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                            basename($filename)
                        );

                }
```

On server, the pdf file is correct.

With this code, only PDF fails ... I'm on it since this morning and i find nothing, someone had an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that `file_get_contents` returns false. Try debugging it with:

```
if ( $filename != '' )
{

    $path    = Mage::getBaseDir( 'tmp' ) . '/pjcontact/' . $filename;

    Mage::log("File found in {$path}? ".(file_exists($path)?"Yes":"No").". Is it readable? ".(is_readable($path)?"Yes":"No"));

    $mailTemplate
        ->getMail()
        ->createAttachment(
            file_get_contents( $path ),
            Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
            Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
            basename( $filename )
        );

}
```

Comment: Yes, file_get_contents return false ... But it works with .jpg, .png , ... 
I have to put something for a pdf file ? I never saw that !

Comment: The file does probably not exist. It'll work with any file that *exists* (and is readable to the user running PHP), no matter the filetype and extension. Please verify that :)

Comment: But my file is on my server, i don't understand how it can't exist.

Comment: Which permissions is on the file? And what does the log say when you use the example code above?

Comment: Log return : 2015-10-15T15:27:13+00:00 ALERT (1): File found in /home/my_path/var/tmp/pjcontact/Krishnak_pdf_krishnak_test.pdf? Yes

And permissions are : rwxr-xr-x on this file

Comment: I found, when my file name contain space, i found it but i failed to load it, and when i replace ' ' by '_' it works ! Thanks, you put me on the good way !